# Get text from specific tags

Tags: java, jsoup

Suppose I have some html form.

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fistname" value="Mickey" />
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to print this same as given in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_input_tag.htm

like

First Name : .........

Last name ......

I am able to taken input values. All I need is a way to read this first name last name text ( that is the text just before the input tags ).

I have seen methods like .text() or else in jsoups but they give all the text inside the tag. I want specific text. thank you.

Comment: Could you by any chance put the 'First name:' in a '<p>' tag and give it an id or is the content of the HTML not in your control?

Comment: I am finding it very hard

Comment: also html is not in my control. it can be in any format.

Comment: I apologise as I cannot help you due to my lack of experience with JSoup. Any reason in particular to why your not using Java's built in DOM parser?

Comment: no need for apology. We all reach there at some point. I have done most of the code in jsoup. if you can tell me how to do it in DOM then may be i can handle out the rest??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this using Java's built in DOM, you could do the following:

This code will find the first preceding text node to all of the elements in the document with the `input` tag. You can use `Element#getAttribute` to check whether the input element is an actual text input field rather than the submit button.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("doc.xml"));//Load document from any InputSource or InputStream
//Loop through all nodes with the input tag:
NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
    Node n = nl.item(i);
    if(n.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        continue;
    Element e = (Element)n;
    Node previous = e;
    //Loop through all nodes before the input element:
    while((previous = previous.getPreviousSibling()) != null){
        if(previous.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE && previous.getTextContent().replaceAll("\\s+", "").length() > 0){
            System.out.println(previous.getTextContent().trim()); //Remove whitepsace from beginning and end of the text.
            break; //Break after finding the first text element of appropriate length.
        }
    }
}
```

Although I don't know anything about JSoup, I would assume you can access previous elements similarly to how you can in the code above.

### General note to readers

I have used DOM rather than JSoup, please note that the OP asked for this in the comments.

Comment: does this also work for html?? i don't know DOM but i was under the impression that it is mainly used for xml

Comment: @PraveenRana It does work for HTML as it is, in essence, XML. However, DOM has very strict formatting rules so will not accept any documents which have ill formatting such as unclosed tags.

Comment: there is no </input> in html that's why it isn't parsing

Comment: thank you. but i had to use tidy to convert html to xml. then use you code. now it works. i got what i wanted. thank you again for reaching me there.

Comment: @PraveenRana im glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use labels.

```
<form action="action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fistname" id='fname' value="Mickey" />
    <br>
    <label for="lname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lname' value="Mouse" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can then get the label value as:
`$('label[for="'+ this.id +'"]').text()`

Another option would be to use data attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" data-descriptor="Last Name" value="mouse"/>
```

And you can get the value as:
`$(this).data('descriptor')`

I don't offhand know the non-jquery counterparts to these but should be simple enough.

Comment: i am reading data from url. And there can be more labels. I don't need to include all the labels.

Comment: Oh, like your getting html from a url and want to parse it out?

Comment: I am trying to create something like fpdf.org .I have to read data from html url. convert it in php variable format using java. and write all this to a pdf file.